# PHP download code is not working on mobile devices

Tags: php

PHP download is not working on mobile devices but it is perfectly working on PC..
This is my code...

```
session_start();

 $path      = 'editedPic/';
 $image         = $_REQUEST['image'];
 $mainimage  = $path.$image; 
 $username   = $_SESSION['username'];
 $string    = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $username);

 header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$string.'.jpg"');

 readfile($mainimage);
```

Comment: What is it doing instead?

Comment: This is the code that i am using for downloading images but it is not working on mobile devices like android and iphone.

Comment: Where does that code run, on the server in a webserver/browser setup or as program on the mobile device? Point is, if it runs on the webserver, it can not possibly cause failures on the mobile device except by the answer it delivers. Chances are that either it delivers a different answer or that the answer is interpreted differently. In any case, this then has nothing to do with PHP!

Comment: I have solved the downloading issue on mobile devices...